# How do I change the width of the `td` element in the if condition?

Tags: grails

How do I change the width of the `td` element in the if condition?

```
<td id="sampleID" width="30%" bgcolor=#fff>
<g:if test="${(arr[1].toString() == "Variable1") || (instanceItem[1].toString() =
```

Comment: You put the `<td>` inside the `if` with another `<td>` in the `else` part.  You can't "change" something that's already rendered from within a `<g:if>` tag

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to make  elements with different width based on condition

```
<g:if test="${(arr[1].toString() == "Variable1") || (instanceItem[1].toString() == "Variable2")}">
    <td id="sampleID" width="50%" bgcolor=#fff>
        <div class="inside_if">Successfully changed width</div>
    </td>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <td id="sampleID" width="30%" bgcolor=#fff>
        <div class="inside_if">Successfully changed width</div>
    </td>
</g:else>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a big if condition so might be better in scriptlet block...

```
<%
    def sampleIdWidth = (arr[1].toString() == "Variable1") || (instanceItem[1].toString() == "Variable2") ? "40" : "50"
%>

<td id="sampleID" width="${sampleIdWidth}%" bgcolor=#fff>
...
```